# How to setup or use sftp cachingSessionFactory?

Tags: spring, session, caching, spring-integration, sftp

I tried to follow the spring integration SFTP adapter to setup the data feed from local directory to remote site with sftp outbound channel adapter.  The feed basically works fine.

But I would like to use cached connection.  With the official 
guideline for cachingSessionFactory setup:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-session-caching

```
<bean id="sftpSessionFactory"
     class="org.springframework.integration.sftp.session.DefaultSftpSessionFactory">
     <property name="host" value="localhost"/>
</bean>

<bean id="cachingSessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.integration.file.remote.session.CachingSessionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="sftpSessionFactory"/>
    <constructor-arg value="10"/>
    <property name="sessionWaitTimeout" value="1000"/>
</bean>
```

But seems even if I have the sftp-session-caching defined, the sftp session will be closed once a file is sent successfully?

Anyone has experience on this?

Comment: I found there's a thread talking about cache-sessions parameter in outbound channel adapter.  But we don't have this parameter any more since v3.0.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35223101/spring-integration-outbound-channel-adapters-not-closing-the-open-sockets-and-le

Comment: Another thread reporting the same issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32114088/unable-to-cache-sftp-connection-with-spring-integration#